# How can I stop my dog from chewing on everything.

Tags: dogs, training, chewing

My dog is a 1 year old German shepherd in human years and 7 in dog years. He's a good boy but he chews on everything. He chews on trash, drywall, plastic, clothing. Everything. I always have to get it out of his mouth but he never learns when to stop. Even when we say "No!" or "Stop!" He doesn't listen. My parents want to get rid of him and trainers some good trainers cost a lot and we don't have that kind of money. I don't know what to do and I've tried a lot of things. Please help me and tell me what has worked for you!

Answer (score 4):

If there are certain things he chews on a lot, you can get bitter apple spray which works really well to deter them. For general chewing, make sure he has lots of chew toys and bones that will keep him entertained. If he likes to chew, he's going to chew no matter what. So you have to give him things that are okay to chew on. Buffalo horns and antlers last a LONG time and are great for aggressive chewers. You can get them online or at any pet store

Comment: +1 I have a dog who absolutely loves chewing, the only solution we found to help with that was to find toys she loves to chew on more than our furniture.

Answer (score 3):

You are making the most typical mistake any 'new' dog owner makes regarding chewing on stuff.

You need to be very careful now and preferably do as described below or your dog will get into the habit and you will never be able to get the habit out of his system:

1. Make sure you never do anything when he actually chews stuff he should not be chewing: **ignore the bad behavior.** When your dog is chewing on stuff, just start playing with a chew he can actually have, give that lots and lots of interest, your dog will eventually come to you and be more interested in the once he can have you should never ever drag things out of his mouth, you are giving him attention for bad behaviour, never ever say or shout 'no' or 'stop' to your dog, you're giving him attention for bad behaviour.
2. Instead, say 'good boy' and 'well done' when he actually chews the good things, **reward the good behavior**, give him lots of cuddles and attention when he is chewing his rope (my preferable advised toy).
3. Make sure he is not bored, walk him regularly and frequently feed him little bits.

P.S. If you are already worried about the price for a couple of dog trainer lessons, what will happen when your dog might have a serious illness and needs veterinary attention, are you saving up or getting him insured?

Hope this helped.